# Get files names inside a directory path

Tags: php, file

Is there any PHP function to retrieve the file/s name/s inside a directory path?

E.g., I have a CSS file inside `/css`, and I want to get this file's name.

**Solution:**

As @ShankarDamodaran suggested, I used:

```
//Get CSS file/s name/s
chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/css'); //<--- Set the directory here...
foreach (glob("*.css") as $filename) {     //<----Get only CSS files
    $CSSfiles[] = $filename;
}
```

This will return an array (`$CSSfiles`) with the names of the CSS files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of [`glob()`](https://www.php.net/glob) for this

```
<?php
chdir('../css'); //<--- Set the directory here...
foreach (glob("*.*") as $filename) { //<--- Pass *.css , (If you need just the CSS files)
    echo $filename."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<pre>
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('css')) {
    echo "Directory handle: $handle\n";
    echo "Entries:\n";
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        echo "$entry\n";
    }
}
closedir($handle);
?>
</pre>
```

Comment: Good option. But I prefer @ShankarDamodaran 's one. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

***USE***

`<?PHP echo realpath('YOURFILE.PHP');?>`

[CHECK HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_realpath.asp)

Comment: Is this retrieving the file name or the directory name?

Comment: @ManoloSalsas ,I HAVE EDITED MY ANSWER..YOU CAN JUST CHECK

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @nKn ,yOU ARE ABSOLUTELY RIGHT..SINCE `REALPATH` WAS A KEYWORD I JUST GAVE THE FULL ANSWER..EITHERWAY I ALSO GAVE A LINK FOR REFERENCE